# Android dialog Alert

Tags: android

I want to create a `ToDoList` application for android. For Entering ToDoItem i am using alert , This is working properly. But now i want to show a datepicker also in alert. But it is not adding both view

```
(EditText and DatePicker) in alert. MyCoding is

final AlertDialog.Builder al = new AlertDialog.Builder(obj);
             al.setMessage("ToDo Item");

                // Set an EditText view to get user input 
                final EditText input = new EditText(obj);
                final DatePicker dat= new DatePicker(obj);
                al.setView(input);
                al.setView(dat);

                al.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                  toDoItems.add(0,input.getText().toString());
                  aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
                  }
                });

                al.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                      }
                    });
                al.show();
```

Please suggest me what to do ?

Comment: You should read this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog

Comment: go to
to add image and text you want to show in ur alert dialog box...
http://stackoverflow.com/a/10861216/1428123 and edit in ur java code like below
http://stackoverflow.com/a/10861174/1428123

Answer (score 1):

AlertDialog displays one, two or three views. But you want to display more than three views, so try using CustomDialog instead.

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to create a custom dialog where you can put any widget in it. Please Look at the following links:

- [AndroGames - Custom Android Dialog](http://blog.androgames.net/10/custom-android-dialog/)
- [AndroidPeople - Android Custom Dialog Example](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-dialog-example)
- [AndDev.org - Custom Alert Dialog Based on Activity](http://www.anddev.org/bosicc_custom_alert_dialog_based_on_activity-t7928.html)